# Selecting lastest date per ID in QGIS field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, date

My GeoPackage contains columns like `ID`, `date` and `number`.

There are multiple entries/columns per ID for different dates with different numbers: e.g.

```
ID      date  number
 1  31.01.22      10

 1  31.12.22      15

 2  31.03.22       7

 2  31.06.22      20
```

I want to select only the newest entry per ID.

Has anyone an idea how to select the latest dates for each ID with the field calculator?

Comment: Type of `date` field is `Date` or `String(Text)`?

Comment: 31.06.22  is an invalid date.

Answer (score 1):

If type of `date` field is `Date` use the following expression in "Select by Expression" window:

```
"date" = to_date(maximum("date", group_by:="ID"))
```

Comment: thank you, I think in general it would work as the type is Date. Unfortunately, it seems that the dataset is too big because it crashes QGIS.